# UIPicker set selected row by title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, ios4

I would like to set UIPicker selected row by title, I'm using the code below, but it's not working, what I'm missing?

```
// data from sqlite db

test2 =[[NSString alloc]
                    initWithUTF8String:
                    (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];


NSLog(@"%@", test2); // 400 (the value)
[self.myPickerView selectRow:[[[NSUserDefaults 
    standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:test2]intValue] inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

Comment: Why you have [[[NSUserDefaults 
standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:test2]intValue] - shouldn't it be just "test2" ? 400 is a key for a value which you keep in NSUserDefaults ? If so - please print output from intValue.

Comment: - (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[self.myPickerView[test2 intValue] selectRow:nSelectedItem inComponent:0 animated:YES]; }
Try this ...

Comment: thx. there's a syntax error at intValue

Comment: @JennyProGram  are you able to correct that ? now that is working or not ?

Comment: [[[NSUserDefaults 
    standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"YourKey"]intValue] is this right ?

Comment: thx for helping me out but it still not working...

Comment: [self.myPickerView selectRow:6 inComponent:0 animated:YES]; //this work fine

Comment: [self.myPickerView selectRow:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"400"]intValue] inComponent:0 animated:YES]; // this doesn't work as well